# How to filter a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How  to filter a string in SQL 2008?

```
SELECT FileName=reverse(left(reverse('\\PRODSERVER\D$\EXPORT\Data20160401.txt'), 

                    charindex('\',reverse('\\PRODSERVER\D$\EXPORT\Data20160401.txt'), 

                             1) - 1))
```

Above query returns the file name which is Data20160401.txt.

I need to fetch only the server name which is PRODSERVER.

Comment: does your filename always start with \\?

Comment: Yes the filename always starts with \\

Comment: is the path always the same? if not, can you give examples of path variations you would expect to be able to query for.

Comment: \\servername\c$\logserver\www\W3SVC1\filename.log       This is the format of the actual file path

Comment: you could start by taking a substring of your path starting after the \\ then get the index where your next \ is located using charindex and then you know where your substring has to end

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to split your string

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Invoke the function

```
select *from dbo.fnSplitString('\\PRODSERVER\D$\EXPORT\Data20160401.txt','\')
```

Output

```
PRODSERVER
D$
EXPORT
Data20160401.txt
```

Comment: what if I need only PRODSERVER ??

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement this piece of split function to my existing select query ..  select col1, col2, split (\\filepath\) as [ServerName] from Table

Comment: Got the answer from Bill

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @path  VARCHAR(50) = '\\PRODSERVER\D$\EXPORT\Data20160401.txt'

Select SubString(@path,3,(CHARINDEX('\',@path,3)-3))
```

Comment: If you are selecting from a table just sub in the column name for @path

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the path of your file always starts with \\ you could do something like:

```
Filename=substring(string,0,charindex(substring(string,2,len(string)-2),'\')
```

Don't know if this is the exact correct syntax as I am not on a machine with any sql processor at the moment but it should do something like this:

1. Get the substring of your string without the leading \\
2. Get the location of the 3rd \ as that is where the part you dont need starts
3. Grab the substring from the substring you created in 1 from first position after the \\ until the position of the 3rd \

Comment: Not quite right. The second argument to SUBSTRING is the starting position within the string passed in the first argument. In this case, passing string as 1st and zero as second will always return the '\\' part of the path. Also SQL Server substring is not zero based. To get the count correct counts must start from 1 and be inclusive. Your method would look more like Select SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@path,3,len(@path)-2),1,CHARINDEX('\',substring(@path,3,len(@path)-2))-1) You have to find Substring twice so the LEN() is correct.

Comment: Alright thanks, wasn't sure about these tbh, had to be quick because i was about to leave work and i just now got back to a computer, I had a general idea but didnt have the time to think it out properly